# How to connect to hdfs using pyarrow in python

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, pyarrow

I've installed `pyarrow` and would like to connect to hdfs file in a Hadoop cluster. I'm having the following line and it give me error.

```
 fs = pa.hdfs.connect(host='...', 50057, user='...', kerb_ticket='/tmp/krb5cc_0')
```

this is the error message I'm getting

```
ArrowIOError: Unable to load libhdfs
```

How should I install `libhdfs`? What other dependecies/settings I need to do?